# firefox rounded div get cropped while transition with overflow hidden to parent

Tags: html, css

I am just doing a simple scale on a rounded div, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hr50o5L/4/).

It works well on Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox a part of the rounded div get cropped during the transition and get back to normal after that.

It can be fixed:

- with a non transparent background on the parent.
- without the `overflow: hidden` of the parent.
- without the rotation on the parent.

But i can't use this fixes for what I am making [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2hr50o5L/10/).

All this stuff works in Chrome and Safari, so if anyone knows why firefox act like this i would be pleased to know.

Thanks

Here is the css :

```
 .petale-wrapper
  {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }

  .petale
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 75px 75px 0 0;
    background-color: cyan;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(60deg);

  }

  .petale:hover
  {
     transform: scale(1.2) rotate(60deg);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(60deg);
  }
```

Here is the html:

```
      <div class="petale-wrapper">
       <div class="petale">

       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: seems to be related - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=944291

Comment: Both examples work for me on Firefox v41 on Windows 7